# Combining Facebook contacts with SIM card numbers

Tags: contacts

I have a new HTC One Mini and I can only import *all* of my contacts from Facebook, not just the ones I want in my phonebook contacts list, so that is really annoying.

Also, I added a few numbers to the SIM card, but I can't combine them with the Facebook contact that ubersync has come up with; I also can't add numbers to the existing Facebook contacts.

In addition, I can't edit the contacts I've added so far to the SIM card, so they can have images like in Facebook.

Adding contacts to this phone is really annoying the hell out of me, am I being stupid?

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain in brief the difference between SIM storage and Phone storage. The later section will contain your solution.

There are two types of storage options for contacts, messages, etc.

**SIM Storage**-The contacts that will be stored in the SIM card of the service provider of your device are called SIM stored contacts.

**Advantages**:-

1. You can have your contacts safely stored and is highly portable. Even if tomorrow your phone crashes (formatting, etc.), you will have your contacts with you and don't need to search for them as when you place the SIM in another device, the contacts from the SIM memory will be displayed easily.
2. Your contacts will be safe and private because most applications have access to only the phone memory but not to the SIM memory, so some annoying apps cannot leak your contacts info to other third party's

**Disadvantages**:-

1. As you know, the SIM card has very limited space, so it cannot have more contacts to be stored.
2. Bigger names cannot be saved as there are restrictions to store a name with a limited set of characters (approximately 6 or 7).
3. If you lost the SIM, then you have lost all your contacts irrespective of the storage area where you stored them.
4. Cannot personalise the contacts stored in the SIM (adding pictures, date of birth, email id, etc.)
5. Double display of contact numbers (if you use what's an app like messenger, it will display double contacts: list 1 with the SIM card and 2 with the WhatsApp contacts list).

**Phone storage**-The contacts which are stored in the phone's storage area and have a predefined space limit by the Manufacturer are phone storage contacts.

**Advantages**:-

1. As the contacts storage area is more you can store more contacts when compared to the SIM card.
2. Personalise add/modify any details to your contacts (third-party apps can add photos, etc. to your contacts display).
3. No double display of contacts if you are using any messenger because all the details of one contact are displayed under a single name.
4. Apps can check your contacts in phone memory and can update it with all the relevant information.

**Disadvantages**:-

1. As your contacts are being stored on the phone memory, your contacts will not be portable because if tomorrow your phone crashes/is modified/updated, then you lose all the contacts because the complete phone memory will be wiped out.
2. You will lose security over your contacts as most applications have access to the phone memory and will eventually leak the data to their servers.

Now coming to the answer, you can simply combine your Facebook contacts with all the details like photos by

1. **Step 1**:-First, move all your contacts in phone memory
2. **Step 2**-Under the display option, disable view contacts from SIM (in order to avoid duplicate from SIM card).
3. **Step 3**-Next as you have your contacts on your phone, you can simply synchronize your contacts with your Facebook mobile application.
4. **Step 4 (not necessary but good to follow)**-After a complete synchronization, restart your device and then you can see the pictures of the user from the relevant apps you use.

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload all of your sim contacts to gmail contacts with email addresses of contacts.
2. Then select the facebook account from the accounts and choose to sync to existing contacts.

It is currently working on my galaxy note 2.

Answer (score 0):

Merge/Add your phone contacts to Google Contacts then use a service such as FullContact to update your Google Contacts with Facebook data. Then, display and use only Google Contacts on your phone and delete all the contacts saved on your device.